# Protective marking on Outlook using excel email vba

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a vba code sending outlook emails from excel. My problem is when I send outlook emails I require to select a protective marking which is always none. 
Is there a code I can use to always select this as none and not prompt me?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although rudimentary (and defeating the purpose), you could use VBA send-keys to circumvent the security prompt.

In my case, I am required press 'n' for 'none' then hit enter:

```
Application.SendKeys "n"
Debug.Print "key sent!"
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
.Send
```